# Swift/AlamoFire: Unable to decode JSON response

Tags: json, swift, rest, alamofire

I'm trying to make requests using [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and decode them using the built-in `.responseDecodable` [handler](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-decodable-handler). The API endpoint I'm hitting is `https://api.linode.com/v4/regions`.

`Request.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

func getRegions() {
        
    AF.request("https://api.linode.com/v4/regions")
        .validate()
        .responseDecodable(of: Region.self) { (response) in
            guard let regions = response.value else { return }
            print(regions)
            debugPrint("Response: \(response)")
        }
    
}
```

When I built and run the binary and call `getRegions()`, I get no output in the console (debug or otherwise). When I change `getRegions()` and remove `.responseDecodable`, like this, I get the raw JSON in the console:

```
    let regionRequest = AF.request("https://api.linode.com/v4/regions")
    regionRequest.responseJSON { (data) in
        print(data)
```

Here is my Region model:

`Region.swift`:

```
import Foundation

struct Region: Decodable {
    
    enum resolvers: String, Decodable {
        case ipv4, ipv6
    }
    
    let capabilities: Array<String>
    let country: String
    let id: String
    let resolvers: Set<resolvers>
    let status: String
    let page: Int
    let pages: Int
    let results: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case capabilities
        case country
        case resolvers
        case status
        case id
        case page
        case pages
        case results
        
    }
    
}
```

And here is the JSON response from the API:

```
data =     (
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                "GPU Linodes",
                Kubernetes,
                "Cloud Firewall",
                Vlans
            );
            country = in;
            id = "ap-west";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "172.105.34.5,172.105.35.5,172.105.36.5,172.105.37.5,172.105.38.5,172.105.39.5,172.105.40.5,172.105.41.5,172.105.42.5,172.105.43.5";
                ipv6 = "2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:659,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:9282,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:b9b3,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:925a,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:22cb,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:227a,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:924c,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:f7e2,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:2205,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:9207";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                Kubernetes,
                "Cloud Firewall",
                Vlans
            );
            country = ca;
            id = "ca-central";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "172.105.0.5,172.105.3.5,172.105.4.5,172.105.5.5,172.105.6.5,172.105.7.5,172.105.8.5,172.105.9.5,172.105.10.5,172.105.11.5";
                ipv6 = "2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:f63,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:f6d,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:f80,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:f0f,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:f99,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:fbd,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:fdd,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:fe2,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:f68,2600:3c04::f03c:91ff:fea9:f4a";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                Kubernetes,
                "Cloud Firewall",
                Vlans
            );
            country = au;
            id = "ap-southeast";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "172.105.166.5,172.105.169.5,172.105.168.5,172.105.172.5,172.105.162.5,172.105.170.5,172.105.167.5,172.105.171.5,172.105.181.5,172.105.161.5";
                ipv6 = "2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:ec8,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:98e4,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:1c58,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:c299,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:c210,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:c219,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:1c5c,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:c24e,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:e6b,2400:8907::f03c:92ff:fe6e:e3d";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                Kubernetes,
                "Cloud Firewall"
            );
            country = us;
            id = "us-central";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "72.14.179.5,72.14.188.5,173.255.199.5,66.228.53.5,96.126.122.5,96.126.124.5,96.126.127.5,198.58.107.5,198.58.111.5,23.239.24.5";
                ipv6 = "2600:3c00::2,2600:3c00::9,2600:3c00::7,2600:3c00::5,2600:3c00::3,2600:3c00::8,2600:3c00::6,2600:3c00::4,2600:3c00::c,2600:3c00::b";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                Kubernetes,
                "Cloud Firewall"
            );
            country = us;
            id = "us-west";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "173.230.145.5,173.230.147.5,173.230.155.5,173.255.212.5,173.255.219.5,173.255.241.5,173.255.243.5,173.255.244.5,74.207.241.5,74.207.242.5";
                ipv6 = "2600:3c01::2,2600:3c01::9,2600:3c01::5,2600:3c01::7,2600:3c01::3,2600:3c01::8,2600:3c01::4,2600:3c01::b,2600:3c01::c,2600:3c01::6";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Cloud Firewall",
                Vlans
            );
            country = us;
            id = "us-southeast";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "74.207.231.5,173.230.128.5,173.230.129.5,173.230.136.5,173.230.140.5,66.228.59.5,66.228.62.5,50.116.35.5,50.116.41.5,23.239.18.5";
                ipv6 = "2600:3c02::3,2600:3c02::5,2600:3c02::4,2600:3c02::6,2600:3c02::c,2600:3c02::7,2600:3c02::2,2600:3c02::9,2600:3c02::8,2600:3c02::b";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                "Object Storage",
                "GPU Linodes",
                Kubernetes
            );
            country = us;
            id = "us-east";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "66.228.42.5,96.126.106.5,50.116.53.5,50.116.58.5,50.116.61.5,50.116.62.5,66.175.211.5,97.107.133.4,207.192.69.4,207.192.69.5";
                ipv6 = "2600:3c03::7,2600:3c03::4,2600:3c03::9,2600:3c03::6,2600:3c03::3,2600:3c03::c,2600:3c03::5,2600:3c03::b,2600:3c03::2,2600:3c03::8";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                Kubernetes,
                "Cloud Firewall"
            );
            country = uk;
            id = "eu-west";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "178.79.182.5,176.58.107.5,176.58.116.5,176.58.121.5,151.236.220.5,212.71.252.5,212.71.253.5,109.74.192.20,109.74.193.20,109.74.194.20";
                ipv6 = "2a01:7e00::9,2a01:7e00::3,2a01:7e00::c,2a01:7e00::5,2a01:7e00::6,2a01:7e00::8,2a01:7e00::b,2a01:7e00::4,2a01:7e00::7,2a01:7e00::2";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                "Object Storage",
                "GPU Linodes",
                Kubernetes
            );
            country = sg;
            id = "ap-south";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "139.162.11.5,139.162.13.5,139.162.14.5,139.162.15.5,139.162.16.5,139.162.21.5,139.162.27.5,103.3.60.18,103.3.60.19,103.3.60.20";
                ipv6 = "2400:8901::5,2400:8901::4,2400:8901::b,2400:8901::3,2400:8901::9,2400:8901::2,2400:8901::8,2400:8901::7,2400:8901::c,2400:8901::6";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                "Object Storage",
                "GPU Linodes",
                Kubernetes
            );
            country = de;
            id = "eu-central";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "139.162.130.5,139.162.131.5,139.162.132.5,139.162.133.5,139.162.134.5,139.162.135.5,139.162.136.5,139.162.137.5,139.162.138.5,139.162.139.5";
                ipv6 = "2a01:7e01::5,2a01:7e01::9,2a01:7e01::7,2a01:7e01::c,2a01:7e01::2,2a01:7e01::4,2a01:7e01::3,2a01:7e01::6,2a01:7e01::b,2a01:7e01::8";
            };
            status = ok;
        },
                {
            capabilities =             (
                Linodes,
                NodeBalancers,
                "Block Storage",
                Kubernetes
            );
            country = jp;
            id = "ap-northeast";
            resolvers =             {
                ipv4 = "139.162.66.5,139.162.67.5,139.162.68.5,139.162.69.5,139.162.70.5,139.162.71.5,139.162.72.5,139.162.73.5,139.162.74.5,139.162.75.5";
                ipv6 = "2400:8902::3,2400:8902::6,2400:8902::c,2400:8902::4,2400:8902::2,2400:8902::8,2400:8902::7,2400:8902::5,2400:8902::b,2400:8902::9";
            };
            status = ok;
        }
    );
    page = 1;
    pages = 1;
    results = 11;
})
```

What am I doing wrong here? I suspect it's something with the Region struct but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Update**:

I simplified my Region model a bit and also added optionals:

```
struct Data: Codable {
    
    let data: [Region]
    let page, pages, results: Int
    
}
struct Region: Codable {
    
    let capabilities: [String]?
    let country, id: String?
    let status: String?
    let resolvers: Resolvers?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case country
        case id
        case status
        case capabilities
        case resolvers
    }
}

struct Resolvers: Codable {
    let ipv4, ipv6: String
}
```

I'm now getting a successful response using AlamoFire (though the everything is `nil` – progress though!):

```
success(.Region(capabilities: nil, country: nil, id: nil, status: nil, resolvers: nil))
```

Comment: copy/paste your JSON to https://quicktype.io/ and check if the struct is right.

Comment: Have you ever checked optionals data? Maybe some of the properties of Region data returns nil? Decoding may fail. Besides, to handle decoding in try catch block is a better approach after getting response json.

Comment: @RTXGamer Had no idea quicktype.io was a thing, thanks! Incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented! I was able to sort this out by adding a missing coding key. I created `Regions.swift`, which looks like this:

```
import Foundation

struct Regions: Decodable {
    
    let all: [Region]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case all = "data"
    }
}
```

The API response is encapsulated in `data`. Once I added this coding key, I was able to get the decoded response I was looking for:

```
   AF.request("https://api.linode.com/v4/regions")
         .validate()
        .responseDecodable(of: Regions.self) {(response) in
            guard let regions = response.value else {return}
            print(regions.all[0].self)
        }
```

Response:

```
Region(capabilities: ["Linodes", "NodeBalancers", "Block Storage", "GPU Linodes", "Kubernetes", "Cloud Firewall", "Vlans"], country: "in", id: "ap-west", status: "ok", resolvers: QuickCloud.Resolvers(ipv4: "172.105.34.5,172.105.35.5,172.105.36.5,172.105.37.5,172.105.38.5,172.105.39.5,172.105.40.5,172.105.41.5,172.105.42.5,172.105.43.5", ipv6: "2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:659,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:9282,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:b9b3,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:925a,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:22cb,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:227a,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:924c,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:f7e2,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:2205,2400:8904::f03c:91ff:fea5:9207"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/paste-json-as-code-quicktype/id1330801220?mt=12) this app from App Store to parse and get decode json, then you can use alamofire to request and take jsonString as response and decode your json response. quickType give your Data Struct with custom jsonDecoder and u can decode ur reponseString like this (data in your responseString):

```
do {
   let json = try Data.init(data)
}
catch let err {
   print(err.localizedDescription)
}
```